# plot rectangular pulse in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot rectangular pulse in matlab but unfortunately I receive this message error:

```
T=sym('T','real');
>> t=-5*T:1/2*T:5*T; 
>> y=5*rectpuls(t,T);
??? Error using ==> sym.sym>notimplemented at 2621
    Function 'lt' is not implemented for MuPAD symbolic objects.

    Error in ==> sym.sym>sym.lt at 812
        notimplemented('lt');

    Error in ==> rectpuls at 22
    y = abs(t)<Tw/2-eps;
```

which could be the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `rectpuls` is not meant to take in a symbol, it has to take in numbers.

You have to set `T` to an actual number (width of the rectpuls).

```
T = 5;
t=-5*T:1/2*T:5*T; 
y=5*rectpuls(t,T);
```

See [`rectpuls`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/signal/ref/rectpuls.html) documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
T = 2.5; % Period
dutyCycle = 1.9; % Duty Cycle

t = 0:0.0001:10;

y = heaviside(dutyCycle -(t - T*floor(t/T)));
plot(t, y)
ylim([-0.5, 1.5])
```

Comment: A comment on how / why your code solves the problem would go a long way to make it more helpful.

Answer (score -1):

T = 2.5; % Period

dutyCycle = 1.9; % Duty Cycle

t = 0:0.0001:10;

y = heaviside(dutyCycle - (t - T*floor(t/T)));

plot(t, y)

ylim([-0.5, 1.5])